# Http Url Connection detail includes GET method although i defined it as POST in my code, how to fix it?

Tags: android

I want to Send data to Web API(PHP) through the POST method, but I am getting the response code of 400, I tried my best to find out but unable to find the issue, when I debugged the code I found that connection request method is GET although I defined it as POST in my code, maybe this is the issue that's why I am getting 400 response code from server, I am posting my code and screenshot also please guide me where I am wrong?

I am adding my code and screenshot also to help you understanding my problem

```
                URL url = new URL("https://www.shifa.com.pk/api/v1/pat_feedback_api.php"); // here is your URL path

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("mr_no", "959700");
                postDataParams.put("key", "1234675434");
                postDataParams.put("name", "sohail");
                postDataParams.put("contact_no", "033360000");
                postDataParams.put("feedback_remarks", "abc");
                Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

               }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally { conn.disconnect(); }
```

Comment: The only explanation which comes to mind is that you are _not_ actually running the above code, but an earlier version which defined the request method to be `GET`.  Please check that your code is compiled and synched up before you run it.

Comment: I already clean, rebuild the project, uninstall the application, but still unable to POST data.

Comment: Hi just my suggestion, please move to Retrofit (https://square.github.io/retrofit/) because you no longer do alot of code. I haven't use this way since 3-4 years ago.

Retrofit is common and powerful networking library for Android.

Comment: What is this method? `getPostDataString()`?